# How convert json string to datatable in c sharp?

Tags: c#, json

I have json string in format below

```
{
    "open": [
                3978,3856,3925,3918,3877.85,3992.7,4033.95,4012,3910,3807,3840,3769.5,3731,3646,3749,
                3770,3827.9,3851,3815.3,3791
            ],
    "high": [
            3978,3925,3929,3923,3977,4043,4041.7,4012,3920,3851.55,3849.65,3809.4,3733.4,3729.8,
            3758,3808,3864,3882.5,3824.7,3831.8
            ],
    "low":  [
            3861,3856,3836.55,3857,3860.05,3962.3,3980,3910.5,3811,3771.1,3740.1,3722.2,3625.1,
            3646,3721.4,3736.4,3800.65,3816.05,3769,3756.15
            ],
    "close": [
            3879.85,3915.9,3859.9,3897.9,3968.15,4019.15,3990.6,3914.65,3826.55,3833.5,3771.35,
            3769.9,3649.25,3690.05,3736.25,3800.65,3856.2,3824.6,3814.9,3779
            ],
    "volume":[
            3937092,1906106,3203744,6684507,3348123,3442604,2389041,3102539,6176776,3112358,     
            3258414,3330501,5718297,3143862,2739393,2105169,1984212,1960538,2307366,1919149
            ],
    "start_Time": [
            1326220200,1326306600,1326393000,1326479400,1326565800,1326825000,1326911400,
            1326997800,1327084200,1327170600,1327429800,1327516200,1327689000,1327775400,
            1328034600,1328121000,1328207400,1328293800,1328380200,1328639400
            ]
}
```

Also I installed Nuget packege Newtonsoft.json

I tried the code

```
var unwrappedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(unwrappedJson, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

but get an error

Comment: Your current JSON doesn't support for deserializing into DataTable. You have to do some implementation by iterating each value of those fields and add into the DataRow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your JSON structure which is an object in which each field is an array of values doesn't support deserializing into a `DataTable`.

You need to *expand*/*transpose* the object data into an array of objects (Sorry, I am not sure which English term is suitable to describe).

```
[
  { "high": /* value */, "low": /* value */, ... }
]
```

For the summary of implementation, you need:

1. Get the column name(s) with the field(s) in the object.
2. Get the number of rows by the number of values in the fields' array (Assume that all the fields have the same number).
3. Get the number of columns.
4. Iterate each row and column (index) to get the respective value by indexes to form an array of values for each row.
5. Add the array into `DataRow.ItemArray` and add the `DataRow` into the `DataTable`.

```cs
public DataTable ExpandObjectToDataTable(JObject jObj)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    if (jObj == null)
        return null;

    List<string> columns = jObj.Properties()
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();

    // Add columns
    dt.Columns.AddRange(columns.Select(x => new DataColumn(x)).ToArray());

    var arrayValues = jObj.Values();
    // Get number of rows by calculating the number of values in the field
    int totalRow = arrayValues.Select(x => x.Count()).Max();
    int totalColumn = columns.Count;

    // Iterate row
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRow; i++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        List<object> values = new List<object>();

        // Iterate field
        for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn; j++)
        {
            values.Add(arrayValues.ElementAt(j).ElementAt(i));
        }

        row.ItemArray = values.ToArray();
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }       

    return dt;
}
```

Caller:

```cs
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
DataTable dt = ExpandObjectToDataTable(jObj);
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DjhJUl)